# Core Data relationship between existing entities

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have two tables of data. One is table_A(id, x, x, b_id) and table_B(id, x).
I would like to add a relationship between b_id from table_A to id of table_B. I already have a JSON data like that, and I tried with Xcode to make so connection, but all I can make is a new relationship between those two.

I'm new to this, so would apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of CoreData in terms of a DBMS which it is not. You don't need to set up foreign keys to make relationships in CoreData. If you want to assign a B table entity to a A you just create a relationship of between the two and you can set the attribute. The foreignKey and linking is all done by CoreData in the background.

Comment: What dou you mean create a relationship and add attribute? You see I already have data for those 2 tables.

Comment: @HelloimDarius Relationships are one of the core concepts of Core Data, and they do not use foreign keys. Check out this page for an introduction: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1